# Invalid version specification on Shiny app

Tags: python, r, shiny, pip, shinyapps

When I try to deploy my (reticulate-powered) Shiny app to [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io/), I get the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : invalid version specification ‘20.1b1’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

While it is not explicit, I suppose the error is refering to the pip version, which I never explicitly specify.

This is the part of the code that precedes the ui and server functions:

```r
library(reticulate)
library(shiny)

virtualenv_create(envname = "elicit", python="python3")
virtualenv_install("elicit", packages = c('numpy', 'Gpy'))
use_virtualenv("elicit", required = TRUE)
```

When I comment this out together with any Python-related code from the UI and the server, everything works fine.

How can I set the valid version the site is requesting? I see that `reticulate::virtualenv` has a `pip_options` argument, but I can't find useful documentation about how to use it.

I am also not very proficient at setting virtual and conda environments, so I could very well be missing some basic step.

## Update

I noticed that if I switch the order of the `use_virtualenv` and the `virtualenv_install` calls I get a different error:

```
ERROR: The requested version of Python
('~/.virtualenvs/elicit/bin/python') cannot be used, as another version
of Python ('/usr/bin/python3') has already been initialized. Please
restart the R session if you need to attach reticulate to a different
version of Python.
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  failed to initialize requested version of Python
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I've tried everything I could think of but I can't get that fixed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a solution for this issue. Since the bugged version of pip gets installed as soon as your create the virtualenv, I forcibly uninstalled it and then installed the version that worked when I built my app. Here is the code that I used:

```
virtualenv_create(envname = "python_environment", python = "python3")
virtualenv_remove(envname = "python_environment", packages = "pip")
virtualenv_install(envname = "python_environment", packages = c("pip==19.0.3","numpy","nltk","torch"), ignore_installed = TRUE)
use_virtualenv("python_environment", required = TRUE)
```

Comment: This definitely gives me progress, but now I get a "no module named 'numpy'" error (even though the package was installed as per your code). Then if I add `py_install("numpy")` inside `app.R`, I get a "could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3" error. I feel like I am missing some basic step.

Comment: That is strange, numpy should definitely be installed through that code in the virtualenv. Though its hard to tell where the issue is without seeing your code. Check the Python function that you import to R using reticulate through ```source_python``` maybe the issue lies in the Python portion of the code rather than Shiny

Comment: I finally got it working. What did the trick was creating a `.Rprofile` file in the Shiny root folder containing `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "~/.virtualenvs/python_environment/bin/python3")` and nothing else. I thought I could pass that path as the `python` argument of `rsconnect::deployApp`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. After I did that, there was no need to even reinstall pip.

Comment: Hi there, I am also meet the same issue and after adding the code you provided, the error disappear but there are new error that about: sh: 1: /home/shiny/.virtualenvs/python35_env/bin/pip: not found
Error: Error installing package(s): 'pip'
Execution halted. Do you know anything happens behind it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this as a comment to the accepted answer, but I'm also posting this as an answer for better visibility and further explanation.

What worked in the end for my case was creating a `.Rprofile` file containing the following line:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "~/.virtualenvs/elicit/bin/python3")
```

That file should be located in the same folder as `app.R` and should be deployed to the remote server. The final `app.R` file looks just like the one posted in the question.

---

**Update:** This eventually broke again, and what fixed it for me was to remove and reinstall pip (as pointed out by theThalamus), but without specifying a pip version. So `app.R` would look something like this:

```r
virtualenv_create(...)  # create virtual environment
virtualenv_remove(envname = "python_environment", packages = "pip")
virtualenv_install(envname = "python_environment", packages = "pip")
virtualenv_install(...)  # install other packages
```

The two `virtualenv_install` instances can probably be merged, but I decided to keep them separate to highlight the fix.